# Importing images hangs at Importing Region

Tags: maas

Fresh install and I can't get images to import.  I see the following in maas.log:

```
Nov  9 13:00:26 bme-maas maas.import-images: [INFO] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v2/daily/
Nov  9 13:00:30 bme-maas maas.bootsources: [INFO] Updated boot sources cache.
Nov  9 13:00:30 bme-maas maas.bootresources: [INFO] Started importing of boot images from 1 source(s).
Nov  9 13:00:30 bme-maas maas.import-images: [INFO] Downloading image descriptions from http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v2/daily/
Nov  9 13:00:32 bme-maas maas.bootresources: [INFO] Importing images from source: http://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v2/daily/
Nov  9 13:16:17 bme-maas maas.import-images: [INFO] Started importing boot images.
Nov  9 13:16:17 bme-maas maas.import-images: [INFO] Downloading image descriptions from http://localhost:5240/MAAS/images-stream/streams/v1/index.json
Nov  9 13:16:32 bme-maas maas.import-images: [INFO] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any new images.
Nov  9 13:36:18 bme-maas maas.import-images: [INFO] Started importing boot images.
Nov  9 13:36:18 bme-maas maas.import-images: [INFO] Downloading image descriptions from http://localhost:5240/MAAS/images-stream/streams/v1/index.json
Nov  9 13:36:19 bme-maas maas.import-images: [INFO] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any new images.
```

Edit: Starting it from the GUI with MAAS 2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.  I tried to do a reinstall of the entire OS from scratch and encountered the same issue.  I then started to try to do it via creating a local copy but ended up going back to trying to get it from the images.maas.io URL.

Here's an sosreport if that helps https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzkCl-Znx04SVVZBbENiYk5XWTQ

Comment: We'll need more information, Maas 1.9 or 2.0?  How are you starting the import, cmdline or GUI?  You need to put more up.   Reading your log says it doesn't work, that's all.

Comment: Starting it from the GUI with MAAS 2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.  I tried to do a reinstall of the entire OS from scratch and encountered the same issue.  I then started to try to do it via creating a local copy but ended up going back to trying to get it from the images.maas.io URL.

Here's an sosreport if that helps https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzkCl-Znx04SVVZBbENiYk5XWTQ

Answer (score 1):

I would try to import using the CLI to see if it gives you any more insight into the problem, or potentially resolves your problem.

It's a pretty good idea to be able to use the CLI as well, sometimes it's easier and quicker to use.  First we start by installing `maas-cli`. The `maas-region` command will return the API key for the user specified.  We will then login with a username/profile name, and the API key retrieved.  We do a `version read` just to make sure we're logged in and ready.  Then we finally issue the `boot-resources import` command which and for 2.0 will automatically import 16.04.

```
sudo apt-get install maas-cli
sudo maas-region apikey --username root
maas login username http://10.10.0.1/MAAS/api/2.0/ '<key>'
maas username version read
maas username boot-resources import
```

Comment: Looks like the commands works but I get the same result in the logs.  Is there a way to up the log verbosity?  

Nov 10 09:59:20 bme-maas maas.import-images: [INFO] Downloading image descriptions from http://localhost:5240/MAAS/images-stream/streams/v1/index.json

Nov 10 09:59:20 bme-maas maas.import-images: [INFO] Finished importing boot images, the region does not have any new images.